# Is Arabic supported by all annotations in Stanford NLP?

Tags: java, nlp, stanford-nlp, arabic

I've used almost all provided annotations by Stanford NLP on English, but I want to work on Arabic now.

The question is, **Could I use all annotations like** `tokenize, ssplit, pos, lemma, ner, parse,dcoref` **on Arabic too**?

**Update:**

I want to know if Arabic has supported annotations like English or not, or is the annotations work on Arabic as well on English?

Comment: the question is not vivid. How and where do you want to use them?

Comment: @root It's not important how and where, my question is if the SNLP support Arabic for all those annotations.

Comment: There are separate packages available for different languages (including Arabic), see the [download page](http://stanfordnlp.github.io/CoreNLP/#human-languages-supported) for more details.

Comment: @MTCoster, I'm sure you know that Arabic has less support than English, so it may has less supported annotations, or some annotations that are not working as well as English. That's my question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Different annotators can produce different annotations. Take a look at this table:

[image]

Reference:

http://stanfordnlp.github.io/CoreNLP/human-languages.html